# Simple code worked in Chrome DevTool but not in TamperMonkey

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, google-chrome-devtools, tampermonkey

**Foreword:** I am amateur, just trying to make my own js script to make some task easier on myself.

I'm using and learning *JavaScript.*

**The code(s) I've tried:**

`window.history.go(-1);`

`history.back`

**What I wanted to do:**
Make a script that goes back a page when it encounters a certain page stated in the `@match` metadata.

**What happened:**
I tested on Chrome DevTool Console and it worked. The page goes back and all is well.
I include it in a Tampermonkey script, and it doesn't seem to work. It's like it's ignored altogether. The metadata seemed to be working fine, since it's the same metadata I used for another script and they work alright.

**My question:**

How can I make this work?

The whole script:

```
// @name         MFP reload 1.0
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1
// @description  reload when encountering error
// @author       Miso
// @match        https://www.myfitnesspal.com/exercise/copy_workout?*
// @match        https://www.myfitnesspal.com/exercise/add_favorites
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

window.history.back();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I had to change the url because I do not have an account):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    https://www.051W.com
// @version      0.1
// @description  Nonsense
// @author       Nonsense
// @match        https://www.myfitnesspal.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.history.back();
})();
```

Remember to enable the script https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7phT.png

Comment: I tried that, and it WORKED!!!

Thank you so much! I would not been able to figure that out! It's probably a simple thing, but you have helped me a ton!!!